# How can I convert this string to a date?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert string "Apr 28 2022 12:00AM" to date. I have tried Date.parse, but it is returning "Nan".

```js
var dtstring = "Apr 28 2022 12:00AM";
var dt = Date.parse(dtstring);
console.log(dt);
```

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with jquery

Comment: `Date.parse()` is not a general purpose parser. If you know the date format you can write your own parser. If not, you could use `moment.js`.

Comment: The bad news? This is way more complicated than it sounds/should be. The good news? There's about a million million examples of how to do it on this site already. Happy googling!

Answer (score 0):

On the MDN documentation page it is said:

> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to
> the standard format the function may fall back to any
> implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing
> algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element
> values in ISO formatted strings shall cause Date.parse() to return
> NaN.

So the date format is as follows
if we correct and write the code is working

```js
var dtstring = "Apr 28 2022 12:00";
var dt = Date.parse(dtstring);
console.log(dt);
```

Comment: That format isn't even close to [the ISO standard one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which is the only one *guaranteed* to work.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. I answered the question in this way to at least show the direction to the friend who asked the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the string of the date, you could just use the Date constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date
So for example:
`new Date('2022-04-28T12:00:00');`

But if you can't change the string, you'll have to use a javascript library that can parse this date.
Here is an example with date-fns and it's function parse:
`parse('Apr 28 2022 12:00 AM', 'MMM dd yyyy p', new Date());`
Here is the link of the documentation: https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/parse